# Errores de compilación, ¿son válidas?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Las preguntas relacionadas a un error de compilación o el fallo de un programa son aceptadas en Stack Overflow en español. Me refiero a los programas que se tiene que bajar el código fuente y luego para utilizarlos hay que compilarlos y que no necesariamente implique que la persona esté programando. ¿Se puede preguntar sobre estas cuestiones?

Por ejemplo, si quiero compilar el kernel de Linux, y no puedo porque esto me genera un error, se puede preguntar sobre esto. O si quisiera compilar la librería SDL para instalarla, aunque todavía no comience a programar.

Comment: Puedes poner un ejemplo

Comment: Son perfectamente válidas, pero probablemente no sean respondidas por que en general, sólo personas que hayan colaborado directamente con el software sabrán su proceso de compilado (que es diferente para cada uno), puedes preguntar aquí, pero lo mejor sería ir directamente al sitio web del autor (github, etc)